# display button when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am wondering how to display a button in the header bar when the checkbox is clicked in a listview. Help will be appreciated

Here is my codepen attempted

```
  `http://codepen.io/Hin/pen/KpGJZX`
```

Comment: Please paste here a short code example explaining your problem. The link to codepen might be fine, but only for further exploration.

Comment: I would do it this way - you can use a button hidden in the header bar. And use `ngShow` to set the button to display when an item in the list is clicked.

Comment: http://codepen.io/cfprabhu/pen/dogEVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the updated plunker : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPevdr

What I've done is modifying the `isCheckboxChecked` function. Now this function have a loop to check if one of all your data is checked. If one have it, it will be display because of your `ng-hide`

```
 $scope.isCheckboxChecked = function () {
      for(var i =0 ; i <$scope.tempData.length ; i++){
        if($scope.tempData[i].checked){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you still add a ng-click after the ng-hide? and add some event listener inside the other scope function?

Comment: Yeah, you can do whatever you want. `ng-hide` only hide your element. Your element is still in the DOM. For example, I had try for `ng-click` and it's working fine.